# Nginx rewrite adding port to final url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

The rewrites are working but nginx is adding :8080 which is prevent the url from loading. The site is secure https  `port_in_redirect off;` does not seem to work at all. ex: `rewrite  ^/telecom(/.*)?$ /telecom-technology permanent;` turns into http://www.domain.com:8080/telecom-technology/ when it should be https://www.domain.com/telecom-technology/

complete domain.com.conf is here https://p.ngx.cc/cb76

```
server {

    listen   8080;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    #server_name www.site.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/site.com_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/site.com_error.log error;

# example of rewrite within _redirects : 
# rewrite  ^/telecom(/.*)?$ /telecom-technology permanent; 

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/_redirects;
    port_in_redirect off;
```

**Edit:** spoke with my server company rackspace and the fix was...

Added 
port_in_redirect off; 
directive to the virtual host however that did not appear to suffice.

Adding 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT 80; 
to the /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params did finally work in preventing nginx from attaching the 8080 port to the redirects.

Comment: Check that `nginx` was restarted after you added `port_in_redirect off;`.

Comment: If you've solved this please answer the question in the box below and mark the question answered.